# Adding Rewrite URL for Base + Children Separately

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a main page and beyond that it has children. I successfully rewrite the children like so:

```
add_rewrite_rule('my-url/?([^/]*)', 'index.php?my-var=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

This works great. But when I try to rewrite the base:

```
add_rewrite_rule('my-url/?', 'index.php?my-var=main', 'top');
```

... it doesn't work. I know, it's getting rewritten by the first rule, so I switched them around, but then the children were all getting redirected to the main page.

Is there a way to make the second rule strict so that it will only be effective if there is NOTHING after the "my-url/" ? This way I should be able to move it first, and all should work.

I have searched the net and found no solution. Maybe it's my terms, but I'm racking myself on this one. I hate regex! Shoot me if it's simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your rewrite rules and the order to the following:

```
add_rewrite_rule('my-url/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?my-var=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('my-url/?$', 'index.php?my-var=main', 'top');
```

**Why the order?**
If the order would be the other way around, the first rule will always apply, so the ruleset would never reach your *main page*

**Why the changed syntax?**
To allow an additional query string to be properly processed. E.g. http://foo.bar/my-url/?my-var=foo and http://foo.bar/my-url/foo/?bar=1 should be fetched to.

**Additionally:** A template redirect, if you want to apply your rewrite rules to query string requests like http://foo.bar/my-url/?my-var=foo:

```
function custom_template_redirect(){
    preg_match('/(\?|&)my-var=/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
    if (
        get_query_var( 'my-var', false ) !== false &&
        !empty($matches) &&
        !is_admin()
    ) {
        wp_redirect(
            home_url(
                '/my-url/'.(get_query_var( 'my-var' )?get_query_var( 'my-var' ).'/':'')
            )
        );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_template_redirect' );
```

Comment: Perfect, works great. Thanks! Thanks for the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for both, slight adjustments to each regex pattern-

```
add_rewrite_rule('my-url/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?my-var=$matches[1]', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('my-url/?$', 'index.php?my-var=main', 'top');
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this would work - I accepted the answer that was below you as it had explanations and was more useful to other users. Thanks again!